# Express 2.5.3 not working on Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, node.js, express, npm

I've installed node, npm and express on my Mac OS 10.6.8 machine. Node has been installed and is under version v0.4.11. Npm has been installed and is under version 1.0.106.

Express has also been installed:

```
express@2.5.3 /usr/lib/node_modules/express 
├── mkdirp@0.0.7
├── mime@1.2.4
├── qs@0.4.0
└── connect@1.8.5
```

However, I cannot use it, calling it on the command line gives me this error:

```
$ /usr/bin/express -s -t jade

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'platform'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/bin/express:34:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:421:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

Could anyone give me a hint on what to do? Thanks!

Comment: It's curious why you have express@2.5.3. I just installed it on Lion using `npm install express` and it pulled 2.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Node.js <0.5.0](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/os.html) doesn't include [`os.platform`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.0/api/os.html). Personally, I use Node.js 0.6.6.

Comment: Sure would be nice if the down-voters would comment so i'd know what's wrong with my answer!